# Processing argv value inside < > : syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu

I am processing the values passed into my c program and it works except when a parameter is enclosed in <>. I am assuming that means its not a parameter, but I need to understand what it is and how to process it.

In the second block I pass in key2 and it prints out but not in the first one.

```
dhruv@dhruv-MS-7B79:~/Documents/GSU/DataSec/test2$ ./worm key < file >
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'


dhruv@dhruv-MS-7B79:~/Documents/GSU/DataSec/test2$ ./worm key key2
key
key2
```

My end goal is to strip out the filename from inside < file > so that I can pipe it to another program.

Here is the bit of code I am using to concatenate all the parameters:

```
  for(int i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++){
    strcat(buffer, " ");
    strcat(buffer, argv[i]);
    char* temp = edit_a(argv[i]);
  }
```

edit is meant to pull out the filename

Comment: `>` is also a character interpreted by the shell for redirection and thus should be escaped when it is to be passed as an argument.

Comment: why is this tagged "data-security"??

Comment: google "linux shell redirection"

Comment: I was working on this for a DataSec assignment, I guess it doesn't really need that tag.